# How can I run a program with additional flags in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to test out this answer:

[_dl_runtime_resolve -- When do the shared objects get loaded in to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049445/dl-runtime-resolve-when-do-the-shared-objects-get-loaded-in-to-memory/3049468#3049468)

But when I try various ways to run essentially the same as `gdb "LD_BIND_NOW=y binary"`,it fails.

How can I run my app with this flag on inside gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices.  First:

```
env LD_BIND_NOW=y gdb binary
```

Or, run `gdb binary` and then inside gdb:

```
set env LD_BIND_NOW=y
run
```

The former will affect the gdb binary itself, which may or may not matter.  The latter might not actually work :-)

Comment: is `env LD_BIND_NOW=y gdb binary` the same as `LD_BIND_NOW=y gdb binary`?

Comment: If your shell is a Bourne shell (like /bin/bash or /bin/sh), then yes.  But the "env" form will work even if you use csh.